# Сделать проверку форм независимыми

Tags: jquery

На сайте расположены две формы, скрипт обрабатывает две формы как одну.
Как исправить? чтобы скрипт обрабатывал их по отдельности.

```
var field = new Array("name", "phone"); //поля обязательные       
$("form").submit(function() { // обрабатываем отправку формы    
    var error = 0; // индекс ошибки
    $("form").find(":input").each(function() { // проверяем каждое поле в форме
        for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) { // если поле присутствует в списке обязательных
            if ($(this).attr("name") == field[i]) { //проверяем поле формы на пустоту
                if (!$(this).val()) { // если в поле пустое
                    $(this).css('border', 'red 2px solid'); // устанавливаем рамку красного цвета
                    error = 1; // определяем индекс ошибки  
                } else {
                    $(this).css('border', 'green 2px solid'); // устанавливаем рамку обычного цвета
                }
            }
        }
    })
    //провека номера телефона
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    if (!isValidPhone(phone)) {
        error = 2;
        $("#phone").css('border', 'red 2px solid'); // устанавливаем рамку красного цвета
    }
    if (error == 0) { // если ошибок нет то отправляем данные
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; //если в форме встретились ошибки , не  позволяем отослать данные на сервер.
    }

    function isValidPhone(phone) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/);
        return pattern.test(phone);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите

```
$(this).find(":input").each(function() { // проверяем каждое поле в форме
```

вместо

```
$("form").find(":input").each(function() { // проверяем каждое поле в форме
```

и

```
$(this).find(".phone")...
```

вместо

```
$("#phone")...
```

соответственно изменив `id="phone"` на `class="phone"`.

Comment: Все получилось Благодарю!)

Answer (score 1):

1. Функцию

   ```
   function isValidPhone(phone)
   ```

   нужно вынести за пределы биндинга

   ```
   $("form").submit(function()...
   ```

   Иначе получается, что каждый раз при попытке отправить форму у вас пересоздается функция.
2. Не создавайте на одной странице елементы с повторяющимися ID. Используйте для каждого элемента свой уникальный ID.
   Но для вашей задачи лучше, как указали выше, использовать классы.
3. **Vyacheslav Potseluyko** правильно вам показал пример: выбираете все формы и циклом навешиваете на каждую свое событие отправки формы. Тогда и привязка будет более адресная.
4. `if (error == 0) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }`

Тут немного лишнего. Форма и так будет отправлена, если вы не вернете false принудительно. Так что достаточно просто

`if (error !== 0) return false;`

Но возврат false - это не самый корректный вариант в данном случае. Лучше "обрывать" выполнение события методом event.stopPropagation() или event.preventDefault() (посмотрите примеры как это делать).

Comment: Благодарю за поправки!)

Answer (score 0):

На чистом JS это будет выглядеть так

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].onsubmit = function() {
    // код
  }
}
```

Comment: Поправьте разметку кто-нибудь хороший:(